# Как реализуется поиск синонимов по базе данных PostgreSQL на PHP?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Как реализовать поиск синонимов выражения по базе данных? Это нужно для выявления различного написания одного и того же выражения. Например, прежде, чем добавить в таблицу товар "Vendor Model Color", нужно выяснить, а нет ли там товара "Vendor Model" или "Vendor Model Something". Кто-нибудь наверняка сталкивался с такой задачей. Подскажите как ее реализовать.

Comment: Это называется Full text search.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301993/postgresql-text-search-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать [полнотекстовый поиск с ранжированием результатов](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING) - если есть результат с рейтингом не менее **n**(определенного опытным путем), то считаем его синонимом искомого товара.

Подобная проверка есть здесь, на Stack Overflow - при создании новых вопросов выполняется полнотекстовый поиск среди уже имеюшихся, с запретом создания нового вопроса при некотором уровне сходства.

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрите возможность использования поиска на основе триграмм.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
create table words (id serial, word text);
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON words USING gin (word gin_trgm_ops);
insert into words (word) values ('Vendor Color'),('Vendor Model'),('Color Vendor'),('Model Vendor'),('Vendor Model Something'),('Vendors Modeling'),('Vendors Coloringing');
insert into words (word) values ('Provider Color'),('Provider Model'),('Color Provider'),('Model Provider'),('Provider Model Something'),('Providers Modeling'),('Providers Coloringing');

-- поиск похожего слова/словосочетания
SELECT word, similarity(word, 'Vendor Model Color') AS sml 
FROM words 
WHERE word % 'Vendor Model Color' 
ORDER BY sml DESC, word;

-- поиск с опечатками
select word, similarity(word, 'Vendar Madel Cilar') AS sml
from words order by word <-> 'Vendar Madel Cilar';

-- pg_trgm поддерживают индексный поиск на основе регулярных выражений
select word from words where word ~ 'S.*in';  -- case sensitive
select word from words where word ~* 's.*in'; -- case insensitive

-- pg_trgm поддерживают индексный поиск по типу like
select word from words where word like '%thin%';  -- case sensitive
select word from words where word ilike '%thin%';  -- case sensitive
```